# Importing table HTML from pandas on html body

Tags: javascript, html, dataframe

I have pandas df, exported to html the result is..

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
<thead>
  <tr style="text-align: right;">
    <th>Flop</th>
    <th>BET 1610 Freq</th>
    <th>BET 1218 Freq</th>
    <th>BET 575 Freq</th>
    <th>CHECK Freq</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>2s 2d 2c</td>
    <td>2.90</td>
    <td>11.91</td>
    <td>36.90</td>
    <td>48.30</td>
  </tr>
  ...5k lines...
```

And i'm trying to import on html normal file and create a filter latter
Any ways to make it please?
Is possible with JS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="go">Search</button>
    <link rel="import" href="3BP-OOP-PFR.html" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Include

- in php `import "file.php";`.
- save both file with `.php` extension.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="go">Search</button>
     <?php
        import "3BP-OOP-PER.php"; // import "3BP-OOP-PER.html";
     ?>
    <link rel="import" href="3BP-OOP-PFR.html" />
  </body>
</html>
```

*I think this code help you!*

Comment: any ways with js? ty alot